# Why Log files have lots of NUL characters?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

**The problem:**

```
185  INFO [2016-07-20 08:24:50,393] ({RemoteInterpreter async opener} RemoteInterpreter.java[open]:115) - Create remote interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter
186  INFO [2016-07-20 08:24:50,437] ({qtp691447552-1500} NotebookRestApi.java[getJobs]:163) - getjobs user ***@***.com, productUser mamm01
187  INFO [2016-07-20 08:25:05,765] ({qtp691447552-1483} NotebookRestA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ INFO [2016-07-20 08:25:50,143] ({qtp691447552-1500} NotebookRestApi.java[bind]:119) - binding user ***@***.com to settingId ***@***.com-__-mamm01-__-21
188  INFO [2016-07-20 08:25:50,146] ({RemoteInterpreter async opener} RemoteInterpreterProcess.java[reference]:103) - Run interpreter process [/home/hadoop/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating/bin/interpreter.sh,     -d, /home/hadoop/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating/interpreter/spark, -p, 35297]
```

'^@' is '\0'(NUL) in the vim editor. Line 187 is incomplete. the last part is lost and overwrited with '\0'. There are many places in my log file looks like that. It's so weird.

**My log4j.properties:**

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, dailyfile

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.dailyfile.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.dailyfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyfile.File = ${zeppelin.log.file}
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] ({%t} %F[%M]:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.dailyfile.ImmediateFlush=true
```

I tried to set Append and ImmediateFlush to true, but it doesn't help.

**My pom.xml:**

```
<slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
<log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

I tried to update slf4j and log4j version, but it doesn't help.

**My pattern of calling slf4j API:**

```
public class NotebookRestApi {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotebookRestApi.class);
  ...
    LOG.info("binding user {} to settingId {}", email, settingId(email, product, hiveSiteId));
```

My Application uses JAX-RS and embedded jetty, I don't know if it's related to the problem. My another suspicion is, Is it possible caused by multiple classloaders?

Comment: can it be caused by multiple threads trying to use same logger instance or write to the same file?

Comment: @ilj No. I think it's thread-safe. Must be some other reason.

Comment: I had a similar problem. We find that it's due to multiple process writing to the same file. I forget to kill my old process before starting the new ones.